# Android HeatmapTileProvider not importing into project

Tags: java, android, google-maps, libraries, heatmap

I am new to Android and working through a [tutorial on the developer site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/heatmap) .
I am getting stuck at the first Hurdle as it states *HeatmapTileProvider* cannot be resolved. The code is below:

```
    mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
            .data(list)
            .build();

    // Add a tile overlay to the map, using the heat map tile provider.
    mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
```

Following the error, I have tried importing *HeatmapTileProvider* into the project. The relevant imports:

```
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlayOptions;
  import com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.HeatmapTileProvider;
```

I can import the *TileOverlayOptions* without any problems but *HeatmapTileProvider* is just greyed and says it cannot resolve Maps. I have tried different variations like:

```
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.heatmaps.HeatmapTileProvider;
```

Do I need to import something else to enable the *HeatmapTileProvider* to work? It doesn't indicate this in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio, you need to add the `android-maps-utils` dependency in your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

You can take a look at the Getting Started section of the [Google Maps Android API utility library project's website](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/). There you will find how to configure your Android Studio/Gradle, Maven or Eclipse/ADT project to use the library.